# Capistrano bitbucket - Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deployment, capistrano, bitbucket

I'm trying to deploy my application using Capistrano towards my DigitalOcean server.

This isn't the first time I've configured a RoR server on DigitalOcean with Capistrano deploys that's why I'm confused; I haven't changed anything in my workflow.

Here is my Capistrano configuration file:

```
require 'bundler/capistrano'
require 'rvm/capistrano'

set :application, "foobar"
set :repository,  "git@bitbucket.org:sergiotapia/foobar.git"
set :ping_url, "http://192.168.1.1/"
set :scm, :git
set :scm_verbose, true
default_run_options[:pty] = true

set :user, "sergiotapia" # The user on the VPS server.
set :password, "hunter2"
set :use_sudo, false
set :deploy_to, "/home/sergiotapia/www/#{application}"
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
set :keep_releases, 1
set :rails_env, "production"
set :migrate_target, :latest

role :web, "192.168.1.1"
role :app, "192.168.1.1"

namespace :deploy do
  task :start do ; end
  task :stop do ; end
  task :restart, roles: :app, except: { no_release: true } do
    run "sudo touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
  end
end

# Add this to add the `deploy:ping` task:
namespace :deploy do
  task :ping do
    system "curl --silent #{fetch(:ping_url)}"
  end
end

namespace :gems do
  task :bundle, :roles => :app do
    run "cd #{release_path} && bundle install --without development && rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production"
  end
end

after "deploy:update_code", "gems:bundle"

# Add this to automatically ping the server after a restart:
after "deploy:restart", "deploy:ping"
```

When running a `cap deploy:setup` and `cap deploy:check` everything comes back green-lighted (working fine).

It fails on the actual `cap deploy` command.

```
** [192.168.1.1 :: out] Enter passphrase for key '/home/sergiotapia/.ssh/id_rsa':
Password: 
** [192.168.1.1 :: out]
** [192.168.1.1 :: out] Permission denied (publickey).
** [192.168.1.1 :: out]
** [192.168.1.1 :: out] fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
** [192.168.1.1 :: out]
** [192.168.1.1 :: out]
** [192.168.1.1 :: out] Please make sure you have the correct access rights
** [192.168.1.1 :: out]
** [192.168.1.1 :: out] and the repository exists.
** [192.168.1.1 :: out]
```

I've already added my `id_rsa.pub` file to BitBucket and also made sure it's added to my SSH agent using the `ssh-add -l` command.

Even testing out SSH from the remote server works fine:

```
sergiotapia@tappia:~/www$ ssh -T git@bitbucket.org
logged in as sergiotapia.

You can use git or hg to connect to Bitbucket. Shell access is disabled.
```

So what gives, why is denying me access to the repository on BitBucket?

Is Capistrano running as a user other than `sergiotapia`? Would that be the cause of it?

Comment: I have this issue too! However, I find that I can deploy as needed if my ssh key has no passphrase. (It's a tolerable solution for some machines.)

Comment: Having the same problem deploying a Laravel app from Window. Works fine from OSX.

Answer (score 9):

Make sure to add your ssh key to the authentication agent:

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

and ensure in deploy.rb

```
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
```

Edit:
If you are losing the ssh-add configuration on reboots, you should do the following:

As of macOS Sierra 10.12.2 Apple added an ssh_config option called UseKeychain which allows a 'proper' resolution to the problem. Add the following to your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host *
   AddKeysToAgent yes
   UseKeychain yes
```

Comment: in current version we should add in deploy.rb `set :ssh_options, { forward_agent: true }`

Answer (score 3):

1. You can setup the SSH agent on the :app server,
2. Setup keys that do not require a passphrase between the :app server and bitbucket.
3. Change deploy_via to: :deploy_via, :copy (No need for the deployed server to checkout files, potentially slower though.)

Comment: `@electrawn`,  we are having the same problem. Do all those steps need to be implemented to solve the problem? Or just step 1 or step 2 is enough.